# EventTypeFilter does not work in web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config, trace, system.diagnostics

I have written a listener that outputs events to the event log. To restrict the output, I have added a filter to restrict the output only to filters. However in my event log , i see information events as well. Has anyone faced similar issue ? My code is below:

```
<add name="MyEventListener" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="MyApp" >        
    <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter" initializeData="Error" />
</add>
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you are using `Trace.TraceError` rather than `Trace.WriteLine`.